# Make UITableView scroll under manually placed UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a modal view controller whose type is UIViewController. On this controller, I have two controls; UINavigationBar and UITableView. They are placed with autolayout where the top edge of the UITableView is equal to bottom edge of the UINavigationBar. When I scroll the table view, I want to see the tableview scrolling under the UINavigationbar (navbar's alpha is set to 0.96f and it works in all other places where navbar is provided by the navigation controller.)

I assume I don't see it now because the top edge of the table view is equal to bottom edge of uinavigation bar so I think that is the reason that it is not going under the UINavigationBar.

So, how can I make the UITableView go under UINavigationBar when scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume I don't see it now because the top edge of the table view is equal to bottom edge of uinavigation bar so I think that is the reason that it is not going under the UINavigationBar.

Correct. So if that isn't what you want, don't do that. Use Bring to Front to make sure that the nav bar is in front of the table view (but not a subview of it). Then change the auto layout constraints so that the top of the table view is pinned to the top layout guide. The top of the nav bar is pinned to the top layout guide too, so now the table view is beneath the nav bar.

You will now have problems with scroll positioning and the position of the scroll indicators in the table view - a content offset of `{0.0}` will hide the first cell under the nav bar - but you can readily fix those problems by adjusting the table view's content inset and scroll indicator insets.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the way to go. I will accept it after I make it work with your suggested direction (Right now, nav bar became fully transparent -- i can see the Done button, just tackling that).